# How can i copy google spreadsheet to gmail using script?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, html-table

Hi I'm trying to copy certain range of cells from google sheet to gmail using script. But it is not working especially the format is changing. How can I copy like 'ctrl+c->ctrl+v' using script? here is my code

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //access to the spreadsheet
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('MAIL')); //access to the sheet by name
  var range = sheet.getRange('C7:I23'); //assign the range you want to copy
  var copy = range.getValues();
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sh.getSheetByName('MAIL'));
  var data = sh.getRange("C7:I23").getValues();
  var htmltable =[];

  //var TABLEFORMAT-> // i want this format just like i made on spread sheet
  //var htmltable = '<table ' +TABLEFORMAT+' ">';

  for (row = 0; row<data.length; row++){
    htmltable += '<tr>';
    for (col = 0 ;col<data[row].length; col++){
      if (data[row][col] === "" || 0) {
        htmltable += '<td>' + ' ' +'</td>';
      } 
      else if (row === 0)  {
        htmltable += '<th>' + data[row][col] + '</th>';
      }
      else {
        htmltable += '<td>' + data[row][col] + '</td>';
      }
    }
    htmltable += '</tr>';
  }
  htmltable += '</table>';
  Logger.log(data);
  Logger.log(htmltable);
  var email_subject = "";
  var my_email = "mail";
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: my_email,
    subject: email_subject,
    htmlBody: htmltable, 
  })}
```

Comment: I think that when you provide a sample Spreadsheet including the input values and the sample output you want, it will help users think of your issue and the solution. Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Could you explain what format is changing?May be screenshots

Comment: i mean i want to know the format of the table.. when i send a email the sheet format and mail format is different. like color line style.  values are not different.